# Call MySQL Stored Procedure in a C application giving an error

Tags: mysql, c

I want to use `CURSOR` of MySQL in an application written in C.

I created a stored procedure

```
CREATE PROCEDURE curdemo(IN id INT)
BEGIN
    DECLARE a INT;
    DECLARE flag BOOL DEFAULT FALSE;
    DECLARE done INT DEFAULT FALSE;
    DECLARE cur1 CURSOR FOR SELECT test.Cars.Id FROM test.Cars;
    DECLARE CONTINUE HANDLER FOR NOT FOUND SET done = TRUE;

    OPEN cur1;

    read_loop: LOOP
            FETCH cur1 INTO a;
            IF done THEN
                    LEAVE read_loop;
            END IF;

            IF flag THEN
                    SELECT test.Cars.Price FROM test.Cars WHERE test.Cars.id = a;
                    LEAVE read_loop;
            END IF;

            IF a = id THEN
                    SET flag = TRUE;
            END IF;
    END LOOP;

    CLOSE cur1;
    END//
```

Here is my table named Cars in database test

```
+------+------------+--------+

| Id   | Name       | Price  |

+------+------------+--------+

|    1 | Audi       |  52642 |

|    2 | Mercedes   |  57127 |

|    3 | Skoda      |   9000 |

|    4 | Volvo      |  29000 |

|    5 | Bentley    | 350000 |

|    6 | Citroen    |  21000 |

|    7 | Hummer     |  41400 |

|    8 | Volkswagen |  21600 |

+------+------------+--------+
```

When I am using the following query from a C application I am getting result = NULL and hence Segmentation fault only when `id = 8` otherwise it works fine

```
 snprintf(statement, 100, "CALL curdemo('%d')", id);
    // Call stored procedure query
    if ( mysql_query(device_table_conn, statement) )
    {
            error_function(device_table_conn);
            //return 1;
    }

    result = mysql_use_result(device_table_conn);
```

`mysql_use_result()` returns a `NULL` if an error occurred.

But it should not return a NULL if CALL returns a NULL or empty result.

Comment: Why are you going to use cursors?

Comment: Before using the cursor I was fetching all the table information and then checking the condition for matching but I read somewhere the cursor gives better result for the same thing instead of fetching all the table only fetching the row or result I am needing. This is only a test case. My actual table has more data. Am I right?

Comment: I did not tested cursors versus simple queries, but I read on mysql.com forum that cursors do not good performance, and they should be used when only cursors can help.

Comment: Hi Devart, can you give me the link to support your reply? Thanks for the reply.

Comment: Yes, here it is - http://forums.mysql.com/read.php?20,622837,622837#msg-622837

Comment: Thanks Devart, will get back to you again after testing the CURSOR and straight MySQL fetching.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Finally got it.

Follow the steps given for handling multiple statements:
https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/c-api-multiple-queries.html

Here is the code

```
    snprintf(statement, 100, "CALL curdemo('%d')", id);
    if ( mysql_query(device_table_conn, statement) )
    {
            error_function(device_table_conn);
            //return 1;
    }

    do{
            // did current statement return data?
            result = mysql_store_result(device_table_conn);
            if (result)
            {
                    // yes; process rows and free the result set
                    num_fields = mysql_num_fields(result);

                    while ((row = mysql_fetch_row(result)))
                    {
                            for ( i = 0; i < num_fields; i++ )
                            {
                                    printf("%s\n", row[i]);
                            }
                    }

                    mysql_free_result(result);
            }
            else
            {
                    mysql_free_result(result);
            }
            // more results? -1 = no, >0 = error, 0 = yes (keep looping)
            if ((status = mysql_next_result(device_table_conn)) > 0)
            {
                    ;
            }
    } while (status == 0);

    mysql_close(device_table_conn);
```

Here it does not return anything for any wrong id (not exist in table) and when id = 8.

Answer (score 0):

Your `read_loop` logic is ... interesting.

So let's walk through it:

1. You fetch from the cursor into `a`;
2. You test your `done` flag;
3. You test your `flag` flag;
4. You test the value of `a` against `id` and set `flag`
5. *You fetch from your cursor again*, overwriting the value of `a`;
6. You test your `done` flag;
7. You test your `flag` flag, which is now `true`, at which point you do the select, *but against the wrong value of `a`*.

When your input `id` is `8`, you wind up fetching past the last row in the table, which is why I think you're getting the null result.

You need to test the value of `a` against `id` *before* doing anything else:

```
read_loop: LOOP
        FETCH cur1 INTO a;
        IF done THEN
                LEAVE read_loop;
        END IF;

        IF a = id THEN
                SET flag = TRUE;
        END IF;

        IF flag THEN
                SELECT test.Cars.Price FROM test.Cars WHERE test.Cars.id = a;
                LEAVE read_loop;
        END IF;

END LOOP;
```

**EDIT**

I have to ask, why not just fetch the price for the specified ID, call `mysql_store_result()`, and then call `mysql_num_rows()` to see if the query actually returned anything?  If you are fetching against a specific row key, then your result set will only ever be 0 or 1 rows, so there shouldn't be an issue with storing it immediately.

Either that, or execute a `select count(*) from cars where id = :id;` first and only proceed if the result > 0.

Comment: Hi John, Thanks for the reply. You think that I wind up fetching past the last row might be the reason I am getting the null result. But I don't think so because the done flag is the handler for the NOT FOUND condition so that the stored program does not terminate with an error. The flag will not set if the NOT FOUND condition wont occur and hence no LEAVE condition execution for wrong id which is not present in the table. My application requirement is such that I want to fetch the price of the next entry for the current id. I have already tested the case you said it fails for wrong id.

Comment: @EdgeGoldberg: That's an interesting requirement, and it would have helped to know that up front.  So what *should* the "next entry" for id 8 be other than an empty result set?

Comment: If no more rows are available then NOT FOUND condition occurs. Therefore result set for id 8 will always be empty result set. I have one question does mysql_use_result() return a NULL for an empty result set?

Comment: @EdgeGoldberg: After reading the [documentation](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/mysql-use-result.html) - hell if I know.  It returns `NULL` for an error condition, but whether an empty result set counts as an error condition is not explicitly stated, at least not in the quick glance I gave it.  Have to say, MySQL's online docs are pretty poor.  Unfortunately I don't know of any better resources.

Comment: Thanks for the reply @John Bode. Will let you know if found the solution. Thanks again.